# How to use Order in a Flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, frontend

I have this section that is flexbox with a flex-direction: column, and i want to put the title as the first element only in the mobile view.

But i don't know how to use the order property to make this work.

[Desktop](https://caelum-online-public.s3.amazonaws.com/897-projeto-front-end/02/compressed_image4.png)
[Mobile](https://caelum-online-public.s3.amazonaws.com/897-projeto-front-end/02/compressed_image5.png)

```html
<section class="section section--team">
      <img
        class="section--team__image"
        src="./imagens/requite.jpeg"
        alt="Time da Instalura" />

      <div class="section--team__content">
        <h1 class="section--team__title">Nossa Equipe</h1>
        <p class="section__text section--team__text">
          O instalura foi criado por uma equipe compentente utilizando que há de
          mais moderno na tecnologia, mas sempre primando pela experiência do
          usuário.
        </p>

        <p class="section__text section--team__text">
          Venha conhecer nossa equipe. Quem sabe até trabalhar conosco!
        </p>

        <ul class="section--team__links">
          <li><i class="fas fa-users"></i> <a> Conheça nossa equipe </a></li>
          <li>
            <i class="fas fa-project-diagram"></i> <a> Trabalhe com a gente </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
</section>
```

My Stylesheet of the Section and the elements. Now, i think it will be more clear to help me

```css
 &--team {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: flex-start;
    padding-top: 3rem;
    padding-left: 3rem;
    padding-right: 3rem;
    background-color: $ocean-blue;

    @media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
    }

    &__content {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: flex-start;
      align-items: flex-start;
      height: 100%;
    }

    &__title,
    &__links li {
      a {
        color: $white;
        margin-left: 2px;
      }

      .fa-users,
      .fa-project-diagram {
        color: $blue-lighten;
      }
    }

    &__text,
    &__links {
      margin-left: 2rem;

      @media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {
        margin-left: 0rem;
      }
    }

    &__title {
      color: $white;
      font-size: $font-xl;
      align-self: center;
      margin-bottom: $margin-sm;
    }

    &__text {
      margin-bottom: $margin-xs;
    }

    &__links {
      margin-top: $margin-xs;

      li {
        margin-top: $margin-xs;
      }
    }

    &__image {
      height: 10rem;
      margin-bottom: 3rem;
      border-radius: 3px;
    }
  }
```

Comment: If you could share your CSS code of this section it would be helpful, and more easily for community members to help you on this topic.

Comment: I added it now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flexbox ordering happens with the `flex-direction` and `flex-wrap` properties. `Flex-direction` specifies the direction of the main axis. It can take the following values:

- `row` (default) main axis: left to right
- `row-reverse` main axis: right to left
- `column` main axis: top to bottom
- `column-reverse` main axis: bottom to top

`Flex-wrap` defines if flex items are laid out in a single line or wrap to multiple lines. It also controls the direction of the cross axis. It can have three values:

- `nowrap` (default) lays out flex items in a single line; the cross axis
  stands in the default position
- `wrap` lays out flex items in multiple lines; the cross axis stands in
  the default position
- `wrap-reverse` lays out flex items in multiple lines; the cross axis is
  reversed

> Flex items are displayed in the same order as they appear in the source document by default. The `order` property can be used to change this ordering.

Here is an example of using flexbox's `order` property:

```css
.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.flex-item:nth-of-type(1) { order: 3; }
.flex-item:nth-of-type(2) { order: 4; }
.flex-item:nth-of-type(3) { order: 1; }
.flex-item:nth-of-type(4) { order: 5; }
.flex-item:nth-of-type(5) { order: 2; }

.flex-item {
  background: tomato;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
  line-height: 100px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul class="flex-container">
  <li class="flex-item">1</li>
  <li class="flex-item">2</li>
  <li class="flex-item">3</li>
  <li class="flex-item">4</li>
  <li class="flex-item">5</li>
</ul>
```

**FYI** the `flex-flow` property is a shorthand property for `flex-direction` and `flex-wrap`.

You can check out [this MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items) web doc for diving deeper.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code in Flexbox

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}


/*************** MOBILE *************/

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 200px;
}

div.orange {
  background-color: orange;
}

div.blue {
  order: -1;
  background-color: aqua;
}

div.green {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.container>div {
  width: 100%;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}


/***************************/

@media screen and (min-width:800px) {
  .container {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  div.orange {
    flex-basis: 100%;
    width: 33%;
  }
  div.blue {
    flex-basis: 100%;
    width: 33%;
    order: 0;
  }
  div.green {
    flex-basis: 100%;
    width: 33%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="orange">1</div>
  <div class="blue">2</div>
  <div class="green">3</div>
</div>
```